# SQLite DB access using clickonce generated shortcut

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, clickonce

I'm using a SQLite DB in my program, and it runs without issue in VS or looking in my debug folder.  I then deploy a clickonce application and after installing it fails to access the database, the exact error I'm getting is:

[image: SQLite Error]

Now if I go into where the clickonce application is installed and run the program from that folder it runs without issue, I only get the problem when using the shortcut generated by the clickonce application.

Anyone have any thoughts on why?  Thanks in advance for any insight.

Code

```
dbCon = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=|DataDirectory|cubeDB.sqlite3;");
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sqlQuery, dbCon);
dbCon.Open();
SQLiteDataReader reader;
try
{
   reader = command.ExecuteReader();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("SQL query failed.\n" + sqlQuery + "\n" + ex.ToString(),
                    "SQL Error", 
                    MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

   dbCon.Close();
   return;
}
```

Comment: Can we see your work as well? And next time, put your exception message as a text, not image.

Comment: Added code, and I was unable to copy/paste as I only get it when I run the program from the deployment, not when debugging.

Comment: Looks like permissions problem to me.